# What are options for creating a website that will only read data from a database (never write)?

Tags: angular, web, database-design, local

I'm designing my website and instead of having a traditional database on a server I figure I can have the data locally instead since the webpage will only ever be reading from it. What are options for a website to access a local database?

I've seen some things that could be my solution like localForage, HTML5 Web Sql Database, Web Storage, JSON structures, and IndexedDB but I'm not sure what one best fits my needs. The data isn't a simple list of things, it will be fairly complex ranging five or more tables, so I don't think a JSON of the data will work very well.

I would like to be able to create and maintain the DB in SSMS. I would also like for it to be able to be hosted on something simple like Github pages.

Comment: Why don't use well-known `XML--(XSLT)-->HTML` toolchain for this kind of static content?

Answer (score 0):

There is no clear answer to this question, but it doesn't really matter what you use as every database works with read/write. You just don't have to use the write functionality. However, since you're asking for options: **SQLite** is also a good one for low-medium traffic websites.